# How to find the character in nth position in a string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, string-function

For example,

```
create table tblvarchar 
(
lngvarchar character varying(500)
)
```

And Sample Row is

```
insert into tblvarchar (lngvarchar) values ('110010000001111101010011110000001101011000001')
```

- How to find out the `character`(this case (`0` or `1`)) in `lngvarchar` field using the position of `character` ?
- for example, the `character` in 15th position of `lngvarchar` is `1`

On PostgreSQL 9.2.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this (start position 15, length 1 example):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(lngvarchar,15,1) FROM tblvarchar;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c2c53/2)

Answer (score 1):

If your data contains only `0` and `1`, you might want to use [bit strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-bitstring.html) instead of `character varying` (`bit varying` in your case).

You can use the `get_bit()` function to get a single bit (but that function use zero based indexing); also `substring()` works on bit strings too (but will give you `text` results).

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2666)